# Unable to locate package after deploying it using workbench

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, visual-flows

I deployed a lightning component zip file using workbench. The workbench says "Succeeded" but in Salesforce when I checked deployment status it shows "Validate: Succeeded" instead of "Deploy:Succeeded". I am also unable to locate this component in installed "Lightning components" list. Therefore, it is also not visible in Lightning Flow so  I cannot use it.Please help.

Screenshots attached
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see in the screenshot, check only is set as "true" which means you have just validated the package and not deployed it. If you want the package to be deployed, uncheck the deploy only checkbox in workbench and try again. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That worked!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

It says that you only ran a validation check. It even shows that in your screenshot (Check Only: true). Since all you did was validate it, it was not installed, so you will not be able to find it on the system yet.

Comment: I feel so silly now. I am using workbench for the first time. I got it installed successfully now :) Thanks a bunch.